# Outlook VSTO recipient MeetingResponseStatus does not update after accepting the meeting

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an add-in for Outlook using VSTO, and the add-in needs to get the `MeetingResponseStatus` from each recipient of a meeting request (`AppointmentItem.Recipents`), but when the recipient has responded to the request, the `MeetingResponseStatus` does not update. I have left it for a long time thinking that maybe it just takes a while to have their responses synced from the exchange server to the client, but after 30 minutes, it would seem that it never updates.

I could get it to update by either restarting Outlook, or by opening the meeting in the calendar, and then simply closing it, but obviously it cannot be expected of the add-in users to restart Outlook, or to open/close every meeting after they received a response from a recipient.

Is there any other way I can force the `AppointmentItem` to retrieve the updated recipient responses? Or maybe another object from which I can retrieve the responses?

Comment: Is this for the organizer or for an attendee?

Comment: For the attendees, I exclude the organizer in my logic since they are treated as an attendee as well.

Comment: That is no what I meant - is your code having problems with the response status when running in the mailbox of the organizer or an attendee?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear when and where you are trying to retrieve the [MeetingResponseStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.meetingresponsestatus?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm2350)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) property value (of the `Recipient` class). I'd suggest checking the [ResponseStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.responsestatus?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm901)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) property of the `AppointmentItem` class first. It returns an `OlResponseStatus` constant indicating the overall status of the meeting for the current user for the appointment.

Comment: Since that is the meeting's response, it is just `olOrganized` and that does not help me at all, I need to get each individual recipient's response to the meeting.

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide any special methods for updating the status. You should get a response as soon as recipients response to requests and your Outlook synchronizes changes with the server side.

Comment: But I am implicitly stating how that does not happen in my question. I do not want to update the status, I want to retrieve it. And when Outlook gets a response from an attendee, you would expect the relevant recipient's response property to be updated in the Outlook client, which it is not, and that is my problem.